# Where did the outline view go in Xcode 4 Documentation viewer?

Tags: xcode4

In the new Xcode 4 Documentation Organizer, I can't find the sidebar outline that lets you navigate through things such as class and instance methods, properties, etc for a given class. Where did it go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you can do in any document is **left-click** the rightmost item in the **Jump Bar**, i.e. the bar at the top. Move your mouse a little and the outline appears.

There is a keyboard shortcut to do this which you can customize: It's called **Standard Editor > Show Document Items** and defaults to `CTRL-6`.

Answer (score 7):

This answer might be too late since the question is asked but hope someone can still get some benefit.

Here we go.

The "outline view" in xcode is actually called "Show Document Items" under menu "View -> Standard Editor"
and the keyboard shortcut is "Ctrl + 6" by default.

Another view you might be interested too is so called "Show Related Items" which also appears under menu "View -> Standard Editor" and it provides the option to see the callers and callees of any function you are viewing. Shortcut is "Ctrl + 1".

Personally, I find Ctrl + 6 is hard to press so I change the key bindings through menu "Xcode -> Preferences" and click "Key Bindings" tab. -- Everyone know this of cause :)

Have fun!!

Comment: your talking about the Document, i believe the initial question was about the Documentation - the outline/list of methods for a class has disappeared (after this question was asked) in Xcode 6.2

Answer (score 0):

I think that what pkananen refers to is the 'Navigator' sidebar, where you can see the 'eye', 'magnifier glass' and 'bookmarks' options in the jump bar.

If for any reason that sidebar is not showing, use "Editor > Show Navigator" option to bring it back to sight.